# Return 0 in if statement, does it means true/false or the program runs successfully?

Tags: c++, c

First, if return 0 statements are removed, my program cannot run exactly. So I don't understand what does this means.

Secondly, one more problem is that it doesn't print the string "Accept 1-4 key only." at the end. If I press others key(not 1-4), the program stop and exit.
When I change if- else if statement to switch. It can run.
I am not able to figure what is going wrong in the program?

```
    char key;
    key = getchar();
    fflush(stdin);//fpurge(stdin);
    //1. play game
    if (key == '1') {
        if (Money >= 0.25) {
            Money = Money - 0.25 + PlayGame();          
        }else {
            printf("\nYou dont have enough money to play\n");
            SaveGame (Money, "d:/SaveGame.txt");
            return 0;
        }
    //2. Save game
    }else if (key == '2') {
        SaveGame (Money, "d:/SaveGame.txt");
    //3. Cash out
    }else if (key == '3') {
        printf("Thank you for playing, you end with %.2f", Money);
        remove("d:/SaveGame.txt");
        return 0;
    //4. Quit
    }else if (key = '4') {
        remove("d:/SaveGame.txt");
        return 0;
    //5. Wrong key
    }else {
        printf("Accept 1-4 key only.");
    }

}while(1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: By *convention* if a program exits with a `0` it's considered "success", and a small positive value indicates an error.

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps it's something else? Have you tried to run your program in a debugger? Or to use a debugger to step through it statement by statement to see what happens?

Comment: `if (key = '4') {`  , something tells me your save game file keeps disappearing

Comment: Lastly, at least the C specification explicitly mentions passing an input-only `FILE*` (like `stdin`) to the `fflush` function as *undefined behavior*. Some implementations implement it as a non-standard and non-portable extension. Please don't do that.

Comment: *"my program cannot run exactly"* - begs the question what that actually *means*. You have an infinite loop. Unless it is broken by some means (`return`, `break`, changing the condition to something besides infinite-true), it never ends.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you very much <3 Thank everyone

Comment: General advice: Floating point math is unprecise (note that even most simple 0.1 cannot be represented exactly), you can easily introduce rounding errors. For cases you have a fix number of digits, as with money/currencies, it's usually better to fall back to integers and calculate in a sub-unit (e. g. cents instead of Euro or Dollar, or a suitable fraction of). Solely output formatting is less convenient then, e. g. `printf(%lu.%.2lu", money/100, money%100)` if using unsigned long...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return 0` is a programming convention that is used during program exit to indicate that the program have executed without errors. On the other hand, a `> 0` return code indicates an error is encountered.

On your question, `if return 0 is removed, program cannot run`. It just means that the function that you are using is expecting an integer to be returned like below.

```
int main() {
  ....
}
```

If you are willing, you can also consider using [switch/case](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/switch-case) statements instead of `if/else`. Note also that there is a logic error on your last `else if`. Should be `key == '4'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have used int main() to run the code. int main() is a function in c/c++ with return type int, hence, you are supposed to use a return statement to run the code without errors.

Now, return 0 is a programming convention which indicates that program has executed without errors.

else if (key = '4') indicates assignment operator, not comparison operator which is ==.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside the `main` function, there are three portable return values: `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. The latter two are constants that are defined in the header `<cstdlib>`. Returning `0` is equivalent to returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`. The values of those two constants are determined by the target system, that is, they will be values that the OS treats as success and failure, respectively.

In short: `return 0;` tells the system that the program succeeded. So does `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`. `return EXIT_FAILURE;` tells the system that the program failed.

There's one quirk here, though: in C++ (but not in C) you can leave out the final return statement from `main`:

```
int main() {
}
```

when execution reaches the end of `main`, it acts as if there was a `return 0;` just before the closing `}`. Personally, I've never liked that; I always write `return 0;` at the end of `main`. Your mileage may vary.